# Modified War Card Game - How run 10,000 hands, record winners of each game,

Tags: python

Consider a modified version of the card game “War”. In this version, there are two players who are dealt 10 cards each, numbered 1 through 10. In each round of the game, player A and player B play a random card from their deck. The player who plays the higher card takes back their own card, as well as the card of their opponent. In the event of a tie, flip a coin to choose the winner at random. The game is over when one player has no cards left.

A. Write a series of functions that simulates the game and calculates the number of rounds each game takes. Run your program 10,000 times and record each result. Time how long the simulation takes.

def_war does not run in the IDE (Spyder). Any ideas what we're misfiring on here?

```
import numpy as np
import time

start_time=time.time()
def shuffledeck(n_cards=10):
    array=np.arange(1,n_cards+1)
    deck=np.random.choice(array,n_cards,replace=False)
    return(deck)

PlayerA=shuffledeck(10)
PlayerB=shuffledeck(10)

def war(PlayerA,PlayerB): 
    rounds=0

    while len(PlayerA)>0 & len(PlayerB)>0:

        if PlayerA>PlayerB:
            PlayerA.append(PlayerA)
            PlayerB.pop(PlayerB)
            PlayerA.append(PlayerB)
        elif PlayerA<PlayerB:
            PlayerB.append(PlayerB)
            PlayerA.pop(PlayerA)
            PlayerB.append(PlayerA)
        elif PlayerA == PlayerB:
            front=1
#            back=0
            coin=np.random.choice(0,1)
            if coin == front:
               PlayerA.append(PlayerA)
               PlayerB.pop(PlayerB)
               PlayerA.append(PlayerB)
            else: 
               PlayerB.append(PlayerB)
               PlayerA.pop(PlayerA)
               PlayerB.append(PlayerA) 
        rounds += 1
    return(rounds)


n_games=10
final_output=np.zeros(n_games)

for i in range(n_games):
    war(PlayerA,PlayerB)
    PlayerA=shuffledeck(10)
    PlayerB=shuffledeck(10)
    rounds=war(PlayerA,PlayerB)
    final_output[9]=rounds
    print(final_output)

end_time=time.time()
```

Comment: This seems like trying to do your homework via stackoverflow.  No one wants to do you homework for you but they will help figure out why something crashed.  But you need to be specific about the problem you observed (described details that made you decide it "_does not run_").

Comment: What do you mean by "does not run", maybe share the output if you are not sure.